# why environment variable removed from my OS?

Tags: environment-variables

I have several environment variable from a text.txt file , i set them with `export variable = value` manually one by one myself in terminal Ubuntu 18.04 but now no one of them appear in `printenv` !
I need to set them somehow never remove again(unless i delete them myself).any idea?thank you

Comment: Are you doing this from the same terminal window?

Comment: No , i set them yesterday (and turn off my laptop in night) and now i use `printenv` . but no one of them appear in environment variables list.

Comment: Environment variables do not come back magically, you need to change your .profile to load them every time you start a new terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your variables in `~/.bashrc` or in `/etc/environment` this way on every reboot they will be exported.
in bashrc should be like this

```
export VARIABLE='<value>'
```

in /etc/environment

```
VARIABLE=<value>
```